# automatically repair rsnapshot config: replace spaces with tabs

Tags: text-processing, sed, whitespace, rsnapshot

`rsnapshot` is quite picky in its config: the commands have to be separated by TABs and not spaces.

if you use

```
rsnapshot configtest
```

you see the errors, but how can I automatically repair the errors and replace multiple space with tabs in the region where it is a problem?

I could use sed:

```
sed s/\s+/\t/g
```

but that would change the whole file.

Comment: Can you give an example of the config file, preferably with both examples for a space that should be replaced and one that should not?

Answer (score 1):

Based on some arbitrary files online ([1](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Rsnapshot) and [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsnapshot)), I came up with a sed statement that replaces spaces after text that looks like a command (letters and underscores) with a single tab:

```
sed 's/^\([a-z_][a-z_]*\)  */\1\t/' input > output
```

The escaped parenthesis capture the command (one or more letters & underscores, starting at the beginning of the line (`^`)), then require one or more spaces to follow that command; those patterns get replaced by the matched command (`\1`) and a tab. This pattern match *skips* commented out lines (because `#` is not a letter or underscore).

Comment: This only replaces the space in the first gap, for example `backup    /etc/                   localhost/` has two gaps, which could contain spaces instead of tabs